# How to make iron-a11y-keys work on the entire page?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

My keypresses (right and left keys) only throw events when I've clicked in certain parts of my page. How do I make it so my iron-a11y-keys work on the entire page?

Here's what I have now:

```
<template>
    <iron-a11y-keys keys="left right" on-keys-pressed="onRightKey"></iron-a11y-keys>
    <paper-drawer-panel id="drawerPanel" responsive-width="1024px" drawer-width="{{drawerWidth}}">

    ...

    </paper-drawer-panel>
</template>
```

It seems to behave the same way when I set `target={{}}`. I'm not certain what the target parameter does so that may be my problem. A bit of education on that would also be appreciated.

Comment: Could you kindly add a bit of clarification as to what the 'certain parts' of the page are, if possible?

Comment: Only if I click in the borders outside of the main content area. I suspect that the keys are being trapped and not bubbled by the other areas. However, that's not the whole story because I just now got it working using the x-tag-trap 3rd-party web component. It's able capture keys no matter where the focus is.

Comment: Interesting! And, as I take it from your snippet, this is all inside of a custom element, not an auto-binding template?

Comment: Correct. It's inside of a custom element.

Comment: `target` needs better documentation and examples, but it sounds like it's what you need.  It's an `Object` property intended to act as the target element to listen for keypresses. I'm not sure how to pass in, say, `<body>` as a binding attribute, so you may have to do it in a script.  I'll see if I can work up an answer with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<template>
    <iron-a11y-keys id="a11y" keys="left right" on-keys-pressed="onRightKey"></iron-a11y-keys>
    <paper-drawer-panel id="drawerPanel" responsive-width="1024px" drawer-width="{{drawerWidth}}">

    ...

    </paper-drawer-panel>
</template>
```

and in the script:

```
ready: function() {
    this.$.a11y.target = document.querySelector('body');
}
```

Comment: This would call the `onRightKey` function when pressing left or right arrow keys, right? How would I prevent this from happening?

Comment: You could use `document.body` instead of `document.querySelector('body')`